# How to rotate the background image when the device is rotated?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to get the background image to stop flipping 90° when the device is flipped 90° so I don't have to add the background image to the drawable's again but tilted 90°. As you can see in the illustration below, what's happening is the background image is stretching its width to fit the length of the device.

What's happening is illustration A and C, I would like A and B though.

[image: I made an illustration to show what my problem is.]

Comment: Do you have any existing XML or code?

Answer (score 1):

Just make layout for landscape.
[Android.com](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: But even if I switched the XML, I would still have to add another copy of the image flipped in the drawable wouldn't I?

Comment: yes it will be different layout special for landscape orientation, i think its better solution.

Comment: also you can handle on orientation changed 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: android:rotationY="180" this will flip the imageView horizontally

Comment: I can see how it would be useful to invest in different layouts for special cases but in this circumstance, I am trying to save as much space as possible. Is there a possibility of using a special landscape layout *and* save space?

Comment: The rotationY, rotationX and rotation did no fix my issue.